# Multithreaded program POSIX

Tags: c, arrays, multithreading, pthreads, posix

This code for Fibonacci sequence using multithreading, but it shows me errors. Can you please check and advise me what I have to do to solve this issue

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>

int arr[100];/* array*/

typedef struct {
        int input;
        int output[100];
} thread_args;

void *thread_func ( void *ptr )/*child thread */
    {
      int i = ((thread_args *) ptr)->input;
      int x;
      ((thread_args *) ptr)->output[0]=0;
      ((thread_args *) ptr)->output[1]=1;

      for(x=2;x<i;x++)
      {
         /* ((thread_args *) ptr)->output[x]= 
        ((thread_args *)   ptr)->output[x-1] 
         +((thread_args *) ptr)->output[x-2]; */
      }
      return NULL;
     }


   int main(int argc, char *argv[])
    {
      pthread_t thread;
      thread_args args;
      int status;
      int x;
      int result;
      int thread_result;
      if (argc < 2) return 1;
      int n = atoi(argv[1]);
      args.input = n;
      status = pthread_create(&thread,NULL,thread_func,(void*) &args );
      // main can continue executing
      // Wait for the thread to terminate.
      pthread_join(thread, NULL);
      for(x=0;x<n;x++)
      {
       arr[x]=args.output[x];/* get the result*/
       printf("Fibonacci is %d.\n", arr[x]);/*print all numbers*/
      }
    }

    return 0;
   }
```

Comment: Wellcome to SO. Please give a more detailed description of what errors you get and where. Also you could use the edit button to remove the triplicate phrasing and to indent your code such that it becomes readable. Thank you.

Comment: To start, when compiling, always enable all the warnings, then fix those warnings.  (for gcc, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic -std-c99` )

Comment: The posted code does not even begin to compile.  the first problem is the extra closing brace '}' after the 'for()' loop in main()

Comment: for readabillity, please indent the code consistently.   suggest using 4 spaces at each level of indention.  4 spaces allows several levels of indenting without eating up the available page width and is wide enough to be seen even when using variable width fonts.  Suggest indent after every opening brace: '{' and un-indent before every closing brace: '}'  suggest a blank line around code blocks (for, while, do...while, if, else, etc)

Comment: You have not mentioned what error did you get. Please add the details of your error as suggested by @JensGustedt. If your error is the wrong value of calculated fibonacci series values, then please note that data type used for 'output' and 'arr' is 'int' which will work correctly till 46th element in Fibonacci series. For higher elements, you need to use 64bit data type (unsigned long long int or uint64_t) and, subsequently, '%llu' specifier in printf() calls while printing the value.

Answer (score 1):

The code is not compiling

You have to remove the closing bracket just before the statement:

> return 0;

Suppose your program is in program.c

You compile like this:

> 1. gcc -g -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -c p.c -o program.o -I.
> 2. gcc -g program.o -o program -lpthread

The option -g is used to debug your code

In order to do the debugging I recommend using some graphical tools like ddd or xxgdb (you can go for other tools if you like)

When you don't supply an argument, your program terminate with code 1 because of the statement:

> if (argc < 2) return 1;

so now when i execute your program like this:

> ./a.out 5     *(to find Fibonacci for n=5 for example)*

it gives this output:

> Fibonacci is 0.
>
> Fibonacci is 1.
>
> Fibonacci is 32684.
>
> Fibonacci is 0.
>
> Fibonacci is 0.

as you see the result is not good right now

the function **void *thread_func ( void *ptr )** seems not working correctly

Comment: actually, the code should be compiled with all the warnings enabled:  suggest: `gcc -g -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -c program.c  -o program.o -I.`  then linked with `gcc -g program.o -o program -lpthread`

Comment: Thank you for the compilation options provided. I’ll update my post. There is warnings when compiling like that. I'm not used to compile like that in the past when I used Posix threads

Answer (score 1):

the following code:

- compiles cleanly
- performs the desired functionality
- generates the correct output
- properly checks for errors
- removes the code clutter

The code does not check for a max command line value of 100, you could add that check

```
#include <stdio.h> // printf(), perror()
#include <stdlib.h> // exit(), EXIT_FAILURE
#include <pthread.h> // pthread_create(), pthread_exit(), pthread_join()

int arr[100];/* array*/

typedef struct
{
        int input;
        int output[100];
} thread_args;


void *thread_func ( void *ptr )/*child thread */
{
    thread_args *arg = (thread_args *)ptr;
    size_t i = (size_t)arg->input;
    arg->output[0] = 0;
    arg->output[1] = 1;

    for( size_t x=2; x<i; x++ )
    {
        arg->output[x] = arg->output[x-2] + arg->output[x-1];
    }
    pthread_exit( NULL );
} // end function: thread_func


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    pthread_t thread;

    thread_args args;

    int status;
    int x;
    //int result;
    //int thread_result;

    if (argc < 2)
    {
        printf( "Usage: %s <maxFibonacci>\n", argv[0]);
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    // implied else, argc is correct


    int n = atoi(argv[1]);
    if( n <= 0)
    {// then command line argument not numeric or < 0
        printf( "command line arguent: %s is not a valid positive int\n", argv[1]);
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    // implied else, command line argument valid

    args.input = n;

    status = pthread_create(&thread,NULL,thread_func,(void*) &args );
    if( status )
    { // then error occurred
        perror( "phread_create failed to create thread" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    // implied else, pthread_create was successful

    // main can continue executing
    // Wait for the thread to terminate.
    pthread_join(thread, NULL);

    for(x=0;x<n;x++)
    {
        arr[x]=args.output[x];/* get the result*/
        printf("Fibonacci is %d.\n", arr[x]);/*print all numbers*/
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: notice, that due to the limitations of the max positive value of a signed int that on a 32 bit system (4 byte int values) that the code will fail to print the correct values when the command line value is greater than 46  the values in the array are correct, so the printf() output can be modified to `unsigned` then the correct values are printed.  I.E. `printf("Fibonacci sequence %d is %u.\n", x, (unsigned)arr[x]);`

Comment: as noted in a earlier comment, a 32 bit 'int' will overflow.   so need to use `long long int` for the arr[] type, etc